# Changing Latex book to html

Tags: html

I tried to convert my Latex book into html code using Klaus Gerhards macros but it did only a few chapters and stopped. It also did not include illustrations (which are in pdf). What can I do?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epsf,epsfig,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\topmargin -0.5in
\oddsidemargin 0in
\textwidth 6.5 in
\textheight 8.7in
\begin{document}
\title{ Working Knowledge: STEM Essentials for the 21st Century}   
\author{Karl Hess}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage 
\input{./Cap1}
\input{./Cap2}
\input{./Cap3}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.